# Run python program from Erlang

Tags: python, while-loop, erlang, request

I want to read some data from a port in Python in a while true.

Then I want to grab the data from Python in Erlang on a function call.

So technically in this while true some global variables is gonna be set and on the request from erlang those variables will be return.

I am using erlport for this communication but what I found was that I can make calls and casts to the python code but not run a function in python (in this case the main) and let it run. when I tried to run it with the call function erlang doesn't work and obviously is waiting for a response.

How can I do this? 
any other alternative approaches is also good if you think this is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: With "read some data from a port" do you mean read it from an external device or a Erlang port? And why do you need to aggregate the data in Python first?

Comment: Yes, The code that we have to read the data is in python and we can not change it since is part of a bigger picture that we dont have control on

Comment: check out the pyrlang project - https://pyrlang.github.io/Pyrlang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to receive some data from an external port in Python, aggregate it and then transfer it to Erlang.

In case if you can use threads with your Python code you probably can do it the following way:

- Run external port receive loop in a thread
- Once data is aggregated push it as a message to Erlang. *(Unfortunately you can't currently use threads and call Erlang functions from Python with ErlPort)*

The following is an example Python module which works with [ErlPort](http://erlport.org):

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

from erlport.erlterms import Atom
from erlport import erlang

def start(receiver):
    Thread(target=receive_loop, args=[receiver]).start()
    return Atom("ok")

def receive_loop(receiver):
    while True:
        data = ""
        for chunk in ["Got ", "BIG ", "Data"]:
            data += chunk
            sleep(2)
        erlang.cast(receiver, [data])
```

The `for` loop represents some data aggregation procedure.

And in Erlang shell it works like this:

```
1> {ok, P} = python:start().
{ok,<0.34.0>}
2> python:call(P, external_port, start, [self()]).
ok
3> timer:sleep(6).
ok
4> flush().
Shell got [<<"Got BIG Data">>]
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Ports communicate with Erlang VM by standard input/output. Does your python program use stdin/stdout for other purposes? If yes - it may be a reason of the problem.